# Why register is registering even if the module when condition is false?

Tags: ansible

I was having a task file which will get container name which has particular volume mounted. The result is stored in container_id variable. This task file need to be executed in linux as well windows. So i added conditional execution but the 'register' variable is behaving weird.

```
- name: Get the container ID for volume "{{vol}}" mounted
  shell: "docker ps -a -q --filter volume={{vol}}"
  register: container_id
  when: ansible_os_family != "Windows"

- name: Get the container ID for volume "{{vol}}" mounted
  win_shell: "docker ps -a -q --filter volume={{vol}}"
  register: container_id
  when: ansible_os_family == "Windows"

- debug:
    var: container_id
```

When i run this in linux node , i thought it will get all the container name in container_id variable. But to my surprise the output is

```
ok: [remotenode] => {
    "container_id": {
        "changed": false,
        "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False",
        "skipped": true
    }
}
```

which means the skipped output from windows module is registered into container_id variable.

Then i placed the debug below linux module as below , which ensured that register at that point of time has proper value

```
- name: Get the container ID for volume "{{vol}}" mounted
  shell: "docker ps -a -q --filter volume={{vol}}"
  register: container_id
  when: ansible_os_family != "Windows"    

- debug:
    var: container_id

- name: Get the container ID for volume "{{vol}}" mounted
  win_shell: "docker ps -a -q --filter volume={{vol}}"
  register: container_id
  when: ansible_os_family == "Windows"
```

The output is as below

```
ok: [remotenode] => {
    "container_id": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "docker ps -a -q --filter volume=origvolfd48c6",
        "delta": "0:00:00.036279",
        "end": "2019-07-30 02:32:13.203036",
        "failed": false,
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2019-07-30 02:32:13.166757",
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "fb81938cdbbe",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "fb81938cdbbe"
        ]
    }
}
```

So the register is having value even if the module is skipped. Why it behaves this way. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the ["Using variables" section of Ansible's Docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables) you'll see this note:

> If a task fails or is skipped, the variable still is registered with a failure or skipped status, the only way to avoid registering a variable is using tags.

So what is happening to you is Ansible's default behaviour. You could modify your `playbook` to use tags like this:

```
- name: Get the container ID for volume "{{vol}}" mounted
  shell: "docker ps -a -q --filter volume={{vol}}"
  register: container_id
  tags:
    - linux

- name: Get the container ID for volume "{{vol}}" mounted
  win_shell: "docker ps -a -q --filter volume={{vol}}"
  register: container_id
  tags:
    - windows

- debug:
    var: container_id
```

Then you can run it using the `--tags` or `--skip-tags` options.